# Cube JS doesn't fetch new records when cubeJs backend API is called

Tags: javascript, mysql, data-visualization, cube.js

I have connected my local Database wrote schemas to fetch data and generate visualizations.

But I observed that the data is not being fetched every time I hit cube.js backend. It is not being updated. I have to restart the server every time to get the updated data. Which I feel is very inefficient and not usable in real-world applications.

Need help to make cube.js fetch the records from the database whenever an API call is made.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Without any code and error message, it will be difficult to give you any help.

Comment: Actually there is no error or code issue here. 
Let's say a table has 10 records. I start cube.js server and visualize these 10 records.
Later when more records are added lets say 2, cube.js server is still fetching the old 10 records. I need 12 records to sync my visualization.

Comment: Then your question is probably off-topic for SO, since this is a programming Q/A site.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this was happing because of in-memory cache which is on by default in cube.js.

reference https://cube.dev/docs/caching